# How does LinkedIn show markup in search results without using schema or microdata markup?

Tags: seo, microdata, markup, linkedin

I've noticed LinkedIn search results include the location and job of the person being searched. I've understood using markup such as `schema.org` can create this but when viewing their source, it doesn't seem as if they're using that.

Are there other options?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you see? What is the search query you are using?

Comment: And in which search engine?

Answer (score 4):

They're using [microformats](http://microformats.org), specifically `hCard` and `hCalendar`. Along with [RDFa](http://rdfa.info) and [JSON-LD](http://blog.schema.org/2013/06/schemaorg-and-json-ld.html), this is an alternative to microdata.

See Google's Rich Snippet spec for people [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146646?hl=en), and [here's](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fdaviesglynn) my public LinkedIn page viewed with Google's structured data testing tool, showing a preview Rich Snippet and the extracted structured data.

Comment: The Schema.org microdata vocabulary is developed and maintained as a joint venture between Google, Bing, Yahoo and later Yandex, so of the available options I think it is the most likely to remain widely supported and stay current enough to be a useful vocabulary. The same is probably true for JSON-LD. It can be tricky to implement as documentation isn't great, so If you're having trouble with an implementation, please post in its own question.

Comment: `hCard` is basically the same thing as `vCard`, and the latter is what LinkedIn seem to be using in their code.